# How to contact the Linux security team

Tags: security

I have a relatively new installation of Ubuntu, and I am still in the process of setting things up / configuring (and also learning of course).

Recently I have done something — nothing dodgy, just following the pattern of satisfying an absolutely legit end-user need — and then I got the impression: "Hmm, what I have done might have a security implication."

In such a case, is there a way to contact Linux (probably kernel?) developers to safely submit a security-related idea / hunch / observation? If yes, how it's done?

Comment: For (late) clarification: 1. I don't have a reproducible behavior that I could call a "bug". Rather, just a feeling that "hm, there's better be something mitigating this thing in general". And it's quite possible (even quite likely) that the mitigation is indeed in place since v1.0. I can't and won't set up an experiment triggering something. If you feel that in such a case it's not justified / necessary to pester the developers, instead of downvoting the question, you could drop a one-liner answer, saying just that (it will garner enough upvotes, I expect).

Answer (score 6):

Since you’re using Ubuntu, you should follow [the procedure for filing security issues there](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSecurity#How%20to%20File). In most cases, that involves filing a bug in Launchpad, making sure that the checkboxes for security issues are appropriately checked so that the security team is notified and the bug isn’t made public.

Comment: Wow, ok, indeed the key was the part: "the bug isn’t made public". I already may admit that I was imagining / hoping for something less prone to user error on the submitter's side (resulting in accidentally publishing it)... Probably I should write them first about my concerns regarding this user interface :)

Comment: The linked wiki page is intended to help you navigate the user interface, and there’s little scope for error: there’s just one checkbox to tick... Going through this will help you get your bug triaged correctly, which is probably a good idea if you’re new to all this.